# jQuery Mobile can call my PHP program but Javascript won't run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm a newbie in jQuery, but I have been pulling my hair out over my scripts for the last 5 days and decided to ask you:

Here's a summary:

- There are two files below:  **Hello.html** calls **Hi.php**.
- If you directly call the Hi.php from a browser, the JavaScript codes (`calculate_cost()` function in Hi.php) run just fine.
- But if you call Hi.php from Hello.html thru its submit button, the
  JavaScript codes (the `calculate_cost()` function in Hi.php) do not
  work.

I think the jQuery 3.21 in the header in Hello.html may be causing this but I'm not sure, and I still need all of these scripts in the Hello.html file to let this code run on a mobile browser.

Would you please HELP me troubleshoot this so I will stop losing my hair any more? :-{

**Test.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
        <title>TEST</title>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js"></script>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script> -->

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">  

    </head>

    <body>

        <form action="Hi.php" method=POST>

            <div data-role="page" id="P1">
                <br><br>
                <div data-role="header" align=center>
                    <font size=6>Enter your number</font>
                </div>

                <div data-role="content">  
                    <br><br>
                    <center>
                        <input type="number" name="C1_TicketID"  data-role="none" autofocus >　

                        <br><br>

                        <a href="#P2" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true">　 Next 　</a>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="page" id="P2">
                <br><br>
                <div data-role="header">
                    <br><br>
                    <center>
                        <font size=6>Click the button below</font>
                        <br>
                    </center>
                    <br>
                    <a href="#P1" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">　Go Back　</a>
                </div>

                <div data-role="content"> 
                    <br><br>
                    <center>
                        <br><br>

                        <input rel="external" data-ajax="false" target="mysite" data-role="none" type=submit name=submit value=" Submit "> 

                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Following is my Hi.php script that is called by Hello.html above.
If you directly call Hi.php from a browser, JavaScript (`calculate_cost()` function) works just fine.  But it doesn't work if you call Hi.php via Hello.html.

**Hi.php**  (for simplicity, this program just dumps an HTML code)

```
<?php

echo <<<SHOW_ALL2


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"> 

    <script>
        function calculate_cost() {

            var i1_price_unit  = 5000;
            var i1_price_qty = $('#i1_qty').val();
            var i1_price_total = i1_price_unit  * i1_price_qty;

            var i1_point_unit =510;
            var i1_point_qty = $('#i1_qty').val();
            var i1_point_total = i1_point_unit * i1_point_qty;

            var price_2 = 650;
            var price_2_quantity = $('#qty2').val();
            var total2 = price_2 * price_2_quantity;

            var point_2 =60;
            var point_2_quantity = $('#qty2').val();
            var total_point_2 = point_2 * point_2_quantity;                

            var grand_price_total   = (i1_price_total + total2).toFixed(0);
            var grand_point_total  = (i1_point_total + total_point_2).toFixed(0);

            i1_price_subtotal = i1_price_total.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+$)/g , '$1,');
            $('#i1_price_subtotal').val(i1_price_subtotal);

            //$('#i1_price_subtotal').val(i1_price_total);
            $('#i1_point_subtotal').val(i1_point_total);

            $('#i1_price_subtotal').attr('readonly',true);
            $('#i1_point_subtotal').attr('readonly',true);


            subtotal_line_2_price = total2.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+$)/g , '$1,');
            $('#subtotal_line_2_price').val(subtotal_line_2_price);

            //$('#subtotal_line_2_price').val(total2);
            $('#subtotal_line_2_point').val(total_point_2);
            $('#subtotal_line_2_price').attr('readonly',true);
            $('#subtotal_line_2_point').attr('readonly',true);


            grand_price_total = grand_price_total.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+$)/g , '$1,');
            $('#Total').val(grand_price_total);
            $('#Total').attr('readonly',true);

            grand_point_total  = grand_point_total.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+$)/g , '$1,');
            $('#Totalpoint').val(grand_point_total );
            $('#Totalpoint').attr('readonly',true);     
        }
    </script>   

</head>

<body id=0>

  <form action="Try3.php" method="POST">

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" >
            <center><font size=4 color=#ffff00>Price list</font></center>
            <table border=0 data-role="table" data-mode="table" class="ui-shadow" id="myTable" >
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th width=82  style="text-align:center;"><font size=2>SKU</font></th>
                      <th width=290 style="text-align:center;"><font size=2>Product name</font></th>
                      <th width=44  style="text-align:right;"><font size=2>Point &nbsp;&nbsp;</font></th>
                      <th width=84  style="text-align:right;"><font size=2>Price &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</font></th>
                      <th width=89  style="text-align:center;"><font size=2>QTy</font></th>
                      <th width=64  style="text-align:center; "><font size=2>Points</font></th>
                      <th           style="text-align:center;"><font size=2>Sub Total</font></th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
            </table>
        </div>


        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <table border=0 data-role="table" data-mode="table" class="ui-shadow" id="myTable">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td width=52 style="vertical-align:middle;"><span id="0"><font size=2>Test_001</font></span></td>
                      <td width=276 style="vertical-align:middle;"><font size=2>Bigger Mac</font></td>
                      <td width=30 style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;"><font size=2><b>510</font></td>
                      <td width=70 style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;"><font size=2><b>$ 5,000</b></font></td>

                      <td width=70 style="vertical-align:middle;">
                            <select id="i1_qty" name="i1_qty" onChange="calculate_cost()" data-mini="true" style="width:100px;">
                                <option value="0">0</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                      </td>

                      <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
                            <input type="text" id="i1_point_subtotal" name="subline1c" value="0" data-inline="true" 
                                   style="text-align:right;background-color:none;-webkit-appearance: none; size:1px;">
                      </td>

                      <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
                            <input type="text" id="i1_price_subtotal" name="subline1p" value="0" data-inline="true" 
                                   style="text-align:right;text-size:5;" data-shadow="false">
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr >
                      <td width=50 style="vertical-align:middle;"><span id=""><font size=2>Test_002</font></span></td>
                      <td width=250 style="vertical-align:middle;"><font size=2>Micro Softcream</font></td>
                      <td width=30 style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;"><font size=2><b>60</font></td>
                      <td width=70 style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;"><font size=2><b>$ 650</b></font></td>

                      <td width=75 >
                            <select id="qty2" name="qty2" onChange="calculate_cost()" data-mini="true">
                                <option value="0">0</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                      </td>
                      <td width=50 style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
                            <input type="text" id="subtotal_line_2_point" name="subline2c" value="0" 
                                    data-inline="true" style="text-align:right;background-color:none;-webkit-appearance: none;">
                      </td>
                      <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
                            <input type="text" id="subtotal_line_2_price" name="subline2p" value="0" 
                                    data-inline="true" style="text-align:right;"  data-shadow="false" >
                      </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                <tr>
                    <td width=5> </td>
                    <td width=230>
                        <a href="Try1.php" data-role="button" data-inline="true" 
                        rel="external" style="background-color:#333366;">　 Start over 　</a>
                    </td>
                    <td width=80 ><font size=2>Grand Total</font></td>
                    <td width=130><input type="text" id="Total" name="TotalPrice" value="0" 
                            data-inline="true" style="text-align:right;background-color:none;-webkit-appearance:none;width:130px;">
                    </td>
                    <td width=10></td>
                    <td width=125>
                        <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                            <tr>
                                <td width=70 >
                                    <input type="text" id="Totalpoint" name="Totalpoint" value="0" data-inline="true" 
                                    style="text-align:right;background-color:none;-webkit-appearance:none;width:80px;">
                                </td>
                                <td width=5> </td>
                                <td widht=50 >point</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>

                    <td width=73> </td>
                    <td  align=right >

                        <input type="submit" name="button" value=" Next " >

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div> 

  </form>

</body>
</html>



SHOW_ALL2;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*doesn't work*?" What actually happens vs. what is expected to happen? Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: In case your hi.php page is called by jQuery mobile ajax, than none of the scripts will run. You need to place your script in on [pagechange](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/) event, or you need to post the form without ajax, was something like `data-ajax="false"` on form tag, info [here](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html). Look at [jQuery mobile events](https://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/)

Comment: @helloworld yes the methods are called in the "pagechange" event of jquery mobile as you are transitioning to another page after submit.

Comment: Oh my god...  Guys, I am so upset with myself having ditched my last 5 days on what you guys can solve in 5 minutes....
I am **SO** thankful with your help and expertise.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!